# Can someone simply refuse to ship merchandise on eBay?

Tags: ebay

I was reading [Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/NotJustUsability.html):

> Another social software success is ebay. When I first heard about
>   ebay, I said, "Nonsense! That will never work. **Nobody's going to send
>   money to some random person they encountered on the Internet in hopes
>   that person will out of the goodness of their hearts actually ship
>   them some merchandise.**"

How does eBay circumvent situations whereby a party simply refuses to ship merchandise upon receiving money?

Does this *scam* or loophole actually work?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how eBay counters fraud. It has nothing to do with the actual functioning of the web app.

Comment: @AlE., I wouldn't assume that. Do you suppose the methods eBay employs to counter frauds by clients/users have nothing to do with the functionality of its client/user interface (web app)?

Comment: WebApps focuses on assistance for end-users interacting with web applications.  As such, I tend to agree with @AlE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends upon a number of details you have not provided (for example timing) but tl;dr is e-Bay guarantee delivery of goods as described. Naturally there are lengthy terms and conditions associated with this, available [here](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/policies/money-back-guarantee.html).

The gist of this is that the Buyer is refunded and, if it happens too often in connection with any one Seller, that Seller will be banned from using e-Bay to sell goods. There may be further protection provided by the chosen payment system.

So, you won't get your goods from that seller but will very likely get your money refunded, provided you act in time and provide required details.

To answer the question in our Title, Yes, but more fool them.

---

[Here](http://ebay.about.com/od/mistakestoavoid/a/ma_reregister.htm) mentions:

> eBay has very sophisticated tools for connecting accounts to one another by name, address, network service provider, bank account information, familial relationships, types of goods being sold, and other, proprietary techniques that are even more powerful.

and some fairly draconian reaction`*` from eBay to attempts to 'bypass' a ban. However `proprietary` (and ignorance!) means I do not know exactly how 'Big Brother' is keeping tabs on me.

`*` Against not just would-be Seller but potentially on other family members and even third parties using the same address.

Comment: How could the seller be banned? It's easy to create another email and credit card with things like Don'tTrackMe